# How can I use bit operators to store values up to 5000 in a array?

Tags: arrays, c, bit-manipulation, bit

I've been learning C for a few weeks and I'm trying to make a program where the user input numbers between 0 and 5000, and when -1 is the input, the program shall print all the previous values in ascending order using bit operators. This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    unsigned int x[200];
    int w, y, z;
   
    while (1){
        printf("Insert a value between 0 and 5000: \n");
        scanf("%d", &x[w]);
        
        if (x[w] == -1) {
            break;
        }
        y = y | (1 << x[w]);
        w++;
    
    }
 
    printf("\n");
    
    for (int z = 0; z < 5001; z++) {
        if (y & (1 << z)) {
            printf("%d\n", z);
        }
    }
   
    return 0;  
}
```

But everytime after the first value is inserted the program ends. How can I fix it? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Initialize `w` for starters. And I have no idea what these "bit operations" are supposed to do and how they help to print the array in ascending order.

Comment: Note that `unsigned int` cannot represent the value `-1`, and `%d` is mismatched with a corresponding pointer of type `unsigned int *`.  Both of these would be resolved by changing the element type of array `x` to plain `int` or, equivalently, `signed int`.

Comment: Note also that `1 << x[w]` and `1 << z` are not going to serve you well, at least for inputs and `z`s greater than about 30.  I am confident that `1 << 5000` is far, *far* greater than your C implementation's `int`s can accommodate, or even its `unsigned long long int`s.

Comment: If the program's input contains the same number multiple times, is its output supposed to contain the same number of appearances of that number?

Comment: What's the biggest number that `int` can hold?

Comment: @JohnBollinger yes.

Comment: @user253751 5000

Comment: @Andrew77 so if I write `int i = 5001` it will error?

Comment: @Andrew77 You seem to be confusing the maximum value of a type with the number of bits in the type. `unsigned int` usually has 32 bits, so it can store numbers from 0 to 4,294,967,295.

Comment: There's no native C type that has 5000 bits. You can use a multi-precision library like GMP to implement numbers that big.

Comment: To be very clear: 1<<5000 would be the 1,506-digit number 1412467032...7191909376, where the ... represents 1,486 digits I left out because Stack Overflow comments are limited to about 500 characters.

Comment: That line of code `y = y | (1 << x[w]);` is never, never, never, never, never going to work, *unless* you change your limit from 5000 to about 30.

Comment: See [question 20.8](https://c-faq.com/misc/bitsets.html) in the [C FAQ list](https://c-faq.com/).

Comment: @Andrew77 it seems like you're trying to use a bitset to track those numbers, not keep an actual list. Is that correct?

Comment: @Carson yes, it is.

Comment: ... and that's why I asked about repeated numbers.  A bit set can track which numbers have appeared, but not how many times each appeared.  You need a different strategy if you want to be able to output repeated numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question tags, I assume you're asking about creating a bitset to store all of the values.

In this case, I recommend creating a special struct, and using functions to access and set the values within the bitset. This will help you understand and maintain your code. Consider this example:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define BITSET_LEN 5000
#define BITSET_BYTES ((BITSET_LEN + 7) / 8)

typedef struct {
    uint8_t bytes[BITSET_BYTES];
} bitset_t;

bitset_t bitset_new () {
    bitset_t b = {0};
    return b;
}

bool bitset_get (const bitset_t * self, size_t index) {
    if (index > BITSET_LEN) {
        // TODO handle error here
    }

    size_t byte_index = index >> 3;
    size_t bit_index = index & 0b111;

    uint8_t byte = self->bytes[byte_index];

    return (byte >> bit_index) & 1;
}

void bitset_modify (bitset_t * self, size_t index, bool value) {
    if (index > BITSET_LEN) {
        // TODO handle error here
    }

    size_t byte_index = index >> 3;
    size_t bit_index = index & 0b111;

    uint8_t mask = 1 << bit_index;

    if (value) {
        self->bytes[byte_index] |= mask;
    } else {
        self->bytes[byte_index] &= ~mask;
    }
}

int main() {
    bitset_t bits = bitset_new();

    while (1) {
        int input=0;
        printf("Insert a value between 0 and %d\n", BITSET_LEN);
        scanf("%d", &input);

        if (input >= BITSET_LEN) {
            printf("%d is too large.\n", input);
        } else if (input < 0) {
            break;
        } else {
            // Set the bit
            bitset_modify(&bits, input, true);
        }
    }

    printf("\n");

    for (size_t i=0; i<BITSET_LEN; ++i) {
        if (bitset_get(&bits, i)) {
            printf("%ld\n", i);
        }
    }
}
```

There are a few things that I changed from your example to make my example.

First, I created a struct just for storing bits. This will let you pass around pointers to bitsets in a more regular way, and improve the clarity of the code. Combined with the creation of separate functions to get and set bits, it's easier to understand which sections of the code do what.

I also chose to use `uint8_t` from `stdint.h` instead of `unsigned int`. `uint8_t` is an unsigned, 8 bit integer. Using an explicity sized type improves the portability of the code. Additionally, if we used larger types we would have to worry about endianess.

In both the `bitset_get` and `bitset_modify` methods, we have to calculate the `byte_index` and `bit_index`. In your example, you tried to shift bits directly by the entire size. You cannot do this. You can only do bitshifts smaller than the size of the field you are shifting. You have to calculate how many bytes over to access, and then what bit index within that byte you wish to access for larger fields.

This is surprisingly easy, because there are 8 bits in a byte, and 8 is a power of 2. This means that for any binary number, we can split it in two.

```
Index format:

01010101
XXXXX-----> index of byte
     XXX -> 0 to 7, index of bit
```

The smaller 3 bits form the index of the bit. We can take just the smallest 3 bits by taking the number `& 0b111`. The rest is the byte index, which we access by shifting the bits over by 3.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are effectively creating a lookup table, mapping the numbers 0..5000 to a bit indicating whether that number was input or not.

For that, you will need 5001 bits. On a system with 32-bit `unsigned int` values, that's will require ceil( 5001 / 32 ) = 157 of them. So 200 is more than enough.

But your logic for setting and looking up bits is entirely incorrect.

What you want to do can be achieved by using integer division to determine the correct array element to modify. The remainder of that division identifies which bit to access.

```c
#define UINT_BITS ( sizeof( unsigned ) * CHAR_BIT )

void set_bit( unsigned *a, unsigned i ) {
   a[ i / UINT_BITS ] |= 1u << ( i % UINT_BITS );
}

int get_bit( unsigned *a, unsigned i ) {
   return ( a[ i / UINT_BITS ] >> ( i % UINT_BITS ) ) & 1; 
}
```

Note that your program removes duplicates outputs. If a number is input twice, it will only be output once.

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted, the OP code demonstrates a misconception. Bits are not *magically* shifted left from one byte (or int) to the next like a game of *Telephone*. The code, written by a coder, has to do the heavy-lifting to achieve what the task requires.

Okay, so you need lots of bits. Any single set bit can only mark if a value has been entered at least once.
Repetitions of the same value would require more elaborate recordkeeping.

Simply define an array of unsigned bytes (each 8 bits wide), initialised to 0's, and sufficiently large to store the range expected (0-5000).
You want to ensure that the number of bits is *at least* sufficient, so allocating an extra byte is insurance and insignificant.

Because the suggested range is positive values to 5000, this code "bails out" when the user enters any negative value.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    unsigned char bits[ (5000 + 8) / 8 ] = { 0 }; // about 625 bytes for 0-5000

    int x = 1;
    while( x >= 0 ) { // terminate on -ve input

        printf( "Value 0-5000 (neg=done): " );
        if( scanf( "%d", &x ) != 1 ) {
            fprintf( stderr, "scanf burped. entry rejected." );
            continue;
        }
        // Use integer division and modulo to set the appropriate bit
        if( 0 <= x && x <= 5000 ) // verify value in range before using it
            bits[ x/8 ] |= (1 << (x%8));
        else
            printf( "%d is out of range. Rejected.\n", x );
    }
    printf( "\n" );

    // now, "sweep" up across all the stored bits (0 or 1), printing when a set bit encountered
    int z = 0;
    for( int i = 0; i < sizeof bits/sizeof bits[0]; i++)
        for( uint8_t m = 1; m; m <<= 1, z++ )
            if( bits[i] & m )
                printf( "%d\n", z );

    return 0;
}
```